# nodejs, postgres, sequelize - instead of getting the filename, trying to get full path

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

After storing my images separately as strings in postgres. when i go to the route, images looks like this (the response i am currently getting)

```
 "images":"image1.png-2020-11-11T13:15:55.692Z"
```

i am trying to get it like this

```
"images":["url":"image1.png-2020-11-11T13:15:55.692Z_full","thumbnailUrl":"image1.png-2020- 
11-11T13:15:55.692Z_thumb"]
```

Here is my get request

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => 
 Post.findAll({
order: [["createdAt", "DESC"]],
include: { model: Post_Image, attributes: ["id", "images"] },
 }).then((posts) => {
const baseUrl = config.get("assetsBaseUrl");

for (let post of posts) {

  const postImages = post.Post_Images;

  const img = postImages.map((post) => post.dataValues);

  const imgFileName = img.map((post) => post.images);

  const IMAGES = imgFileName.map((image) => ({
    url: `${baseUrl}${image}_full.jpg`,
    thumbnailUrl: `${baseUrl}${image}_thumb.jpg`,
  }));
    console.log(IMAGES)
}

res.send(posts);
 });
});
```

when i do console.log(IMAGES), here is my response

```
[
  {
   url: 'http://LOCALHOST:PORT/assets/image1.png-2020-11-11T13:15:55.692Z_full.jpg',
   thumbnailUrl: 'http://LOCALHOST:PORT/assets/image1.png-2020-11- 
 11T13:15:55.692Z_thumb.jpg'
  }
```

]

i was trying to do

```
return{
...post,
images:IMAGES}
```

but it did not work.

Here is the response i am expecting to get from my get request when i go to the route:

```
  "images": [{"url":"http://192.168.1.103:9000/assets/jacket1_full.jpg","thumbnailUrl" :"http://192.168.1.103:9000/assets/jacket1_thumb.jpg"}]
```

Comment: Show an example of data that SHOULD be returned

Comment: i just updated the post, please have a look, it is the last code at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should turn `Post` model instances into plain objects and add `images` prop to each of them:

```
const plainPosts = posts.map(x => x.get({ plain: true }))
const resultPosts = []
for (const post of plainPosts) {
  const { Post_Images, ...postAttributes } = post
  const IMAGES = Post_Images.map((postImage) => ({
    url: `${baseUrl}${postImage.images}_full.jpg`,
    thumbnailUrl: `${baseUrl}${postImage.images}_thumb.jpg`,
  }));
  console.log(IMAGES)
  resultPosts.push({
    ...postAttributes,
    images: IMAGES
  })
}

res.send(resultPosts);
```

if you get a single post only then this should look like:

```
const plainPost = post.get({ plain: true })
const { Post_Images, ...postAttributes } = plainPost
const IMAGES = Post_Images.map((postImage) => ({
  url: `${baseUrl}${postImage.images}_full.jpg`,
  thumbnailUrl: `${baseUrl}${postImage.images}_thumb.jpg`,
}));
console.log(IMAGES)

res.send({
    ...postAttributes,
    images: IMAGES
  });
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224516/discussion-on-answer-by-anatoly-nodejs-postgres-sequelize-instead-of-getting).