# second level include using sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

if user can have many posts and each post can have many images, does this mean that user and images are associated? because currently i am trying to show for each user there posts and for the posts i want to show the images as url and thumbnailurl using the method you stated above. i keep getting an error that Post_Image is not associated to User.

I am currently trying this code and i keep getting an Error Cannot read property map.

```
router.get("/posts", auth, (req, res) => {

let { id } = req.user;
User.findByPk(id, {
 include: [
  {
    model: Post,
    include: [{ model: Post_Image, attributes: ["id", "images"] }],
  },
],
}).then((post) => {
if (!post)
  return res.status(404).send();

const baseUrl = config.get("assetsBaseUrl");

const plainPost = post.get({ plain: true });
const { Post_Images, ...postAttributes } = plainPost;
const IMAGES = Post_Images.map((postImage) => ({
  url: `${baseUrl}${postImage.images}_full.jpg`,
  thumbnailUrl: `${baseUrl}${postImage.images}_thumb.jpg`,
}));

res.send({ ...postAttributes, images: IMAGES });
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it's similar to a processing several posts like in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64788887/1376618)

The difference is where to call `get({ plain: true })`:

```
User.findByPk(id, {
 include: [
  {
    model: Post,
    include: [{ model: Post_Image, attributes: ["id", "images"] }],
  },
],
}).then((user) => { // we got a user here and not a post or posts
if (!user)
  return res.status(404).send();

const baseUrl = config.get("assetsBaseUrl");

const plainUser = user.get({ plain: true })
const resultPosts = []
for (const post of plainUser.Posts) {
  const { Post_Images, ...postAttributes } = post
  const IMAGES = Post_Images.map((postImage) => ({
    url: `${baseUrl}${postImage.images}_full.jpg`,
    thumbnailUrl: `${baseUrl}${postImage.images}_thumb.jpg`,
  }));
  console.log(IMAGES)
  resultPosts.push({
    ...postAttributes,
    images: IMAGES
  })
}

res.send(resultPosts);
```

Comment: why is it the same as processing several calls when im using findByPk?

Comment: Initially you asked about Posts array that you got by `Post.findAll`. It's the same as to get `Posts` array from a user model instance if you indicated `Posts` in `include` option

Comment: okay, now i see why because i am trying to get all the Posts for that user so it is the same as findAll, again thank you

Comment: here is my associations: User.hasMany(Post, { foreignKey: "userId" });

Post.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: "userId" });

Comment: Just add `userId` field to Posts table

Comment: i dont need to add anything to my Posts model post request? I only add a field inside the posts table in postgres?

Comment: just tried it, when i check the database the userId field is null

Comment: INSERT INTO "Posts" ("id","title","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4) RETURNING "id","title","createdAt","updatedAt","deletedAt","userId"; this is my response in terminal

Comment: `userId` should be in both DB and in a model, of course

Comment: yes i add in Posts model, but not in post request i used to store the post in db

Comment: Add to `create` call too